# HTML dynamic dropdown Menubar

Tags: html

Hi I have two linked dropdown menu bar. In the first option i have a list of server names and in the second option i have a list of file names associated with each server name.

example code:

```
var categories = [];
categories["startList"] = ["WEL0282","WEL0855","WEL0703","WEL0704","WEL0706","WEL0707"]

categories["WEL0855"] = ["WEL_log_2014_04.zip","WEL_log_2014_05.xls"];
categories["WEL0282"] = ["WEL_log_2013_10.zip","WEL_log_2013_11.zip",
"WEL_log_2013_12.zip","WEL_log_2014_01.zip",
"WEL_log_2014_02.zip","WEL_log_2014_03.zip",
"WEL_log_2014_04.zip","WEL_log_2014_05.xls"];
```

I need to have a dynamic array such that only the present month file names should be .xls and the previous months file names should be .zip files. Please help me how this can be done.

Comment: This does not really look like an HTML question to me... but dropdown menus are usually built in an un-ordered list.  That is all I can tell you for now.

Comment: There is no reference to months until your question. Do you save that info or what exactly are you trying to do ?